# What's with all the reopens?

Tags: support, review-queues, vote-to-reopen

I opened up the review page and noticed that there were 123(!) posts in the "Reopen" queue. That is an unusually large number, but whatever, things happen.

As I'm going through them, none seem like good candidates for reopening, and none were edited (triggering the queue). I'm expecting all of them to be audits, actually, but none have been. The questions also seem to be largely older ones. I am not sure if that is relevant.

Is it possible someone is messing with the system, or is this just an anomaly?

Comment: I've actually voted a few of them to reopen (although I've noticed I was the only one so far) so I wouldn't say they're all bad. (clarification: I didn't add them to the queue myself, I just voted on those that got in).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, I don't know if any were yours (I got through 15 or so before I it the review limit). The large number combined with (seemingly) low quality is what has me concerned.

Comment: Consider this an opportunity for practicing your **Delete** powers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm tweaking the criteria for feeding this queue.

I said I would do this months ago but... Lazy. *Disgustingly* lazy.

Please try to review in good faith - many of these should probably stay closed, but *not all of them*... As always, **if you can salvage a given question with an edit, *do so!***

Comment: So someone is messing with the system, but its expected! Thanks for the heads up, I will certainly be careful when reviewing. Out of curiosity is their a meta question/blog post detailing the changes?

Comment: Sure: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078 (the bit that sez: "We're still tweaking the exact thresholds for these.")

Comment: Are you tweaking this again?  I've seen several obviously-should-stay-closed recommendation questions in the reopen queue today.

Comment: I've been adjusting the input thresholds slowly over time for... Well, a bit over a year now I guess @JeffreyBosboom. FWIW, if you earn 10K you can vote to delete these if they should never be reopened...

Comment: @Shog9 - What could be a possible benefit in bringing back to life a long dead question without any recent activity?

Comment: @PM77-1 as he said, he's been changing the criteria. It's probably to help the future questions more than old questions and has a side effect of old ones getting in.

Comment: Are these changes network wide or just SO?

Comment: I'm a bit curious about the recent reopen criteria tweaking test (march 2016). Were the results surprising? Did criteria change a lot or not at all? What changed most? If you want I'd be delighted if you commented a bit.