# Old "untouched" questions in a Reopen Queue

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

I've been going through Reopen Votes and noticed that there were quite a few old posts that have not been touched in years.  Like 5 year old post with the last activity 4 years ago.

What brought them back to life?  Is it another case of [behind the scene logic tweaks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256830/2055998)?

[**EDIT**]: As pointed out by [`Jeffrey Bosboom`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298068/old-untouched-questions-in-a-reopen-queue?noredirect=1#comment213575_298068) it is [indeed the case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256827/whats-with-all-the-reopens/256830#comment213148_256830).

Is there any **real** benefit to OPs or community at large in such resurrections?

Comment: See Shog's recent comment on the linked answer.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom - Thank you. It definitely answers the first part of my question.  So I will remove the `support` tag.  I'm still interested in the 2nd part regarding expecting benefits from such action, though.