# Is "serial reopen voting" a thing?

Tags: discussion

I took some time to work on review queues this evening, and came across what to me seemed like a very odd thing: in the "Reopen Votes" queue, four posts in a row were years old:

[is JSP really considered deprecated? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9482852)
[Memory leak checker for Windows that supports GCC? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013337)
[Which code signing authority should I go with? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1077800)
[How do websites use C++ and other programming languages as their backend? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8813624)

Leaving aside for the moment the question of whether these questions should remain closed (they all seem appropriately closed to me):

- What would be the motivation for someone to go through and vote to reopen several very old questions? Specifically, as opposed to someone genuinely believing the questions need to be reopened (it's hard to see in these cases why someone would feel that way), is there some *other* personal gain to be had? **Is doing that "a thing"?**
- My assumption is that these reopen votes were from the same user, but of course I have no way to prove that myself. It seems like an odd coincidence, to see so many very old posts proposed for reopening. Is it one? Or do I just have a flawed understanding of how often this sort of thing happens?

Comment: "What would be the motivation for someone to go through and vote to reopen several very old questions?" Easy, they're a grizzled veteran who will not stand to accept the current state of things.

Comment: @BoltClock: okay, fair enough. I should have been more precise in my wording of that question. I will fix.

Comment: @BoltClock that or [Shog is playing again with the reopen queue.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256830/792066)

Comment: [Every question is sacred!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUspLVStPbk)

Comment: I often happen to vote to reopen very old posts when I stumble upon them (due e.g. to a Google search that leads me there) if I find that they have been closed without the necessary consideration (as often happens). Typically it's completely useless, but to me it's two clicks, and maybe someone is going to gain a "necromancer" badge by giving new interesting insights on a question previously closed by trigger-happy close-policemen.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I understand that dynamic exists. But it seems unlikely to happen so frequently that as a reviewer, I would come across four such posts in a row. I'm not asking about the normal "this question may still be useful", but rather than "these questions all should stay closed/deleted, but someone went through voting to reopen anyway".

Answer (score 12):

Well, let's see.

- The questions were posted by different users, so it's not simply the 250-rep self-reopen in action, and it's unlikely to be a meat-puppet (aka "I have a friend with CV") either.
- There are no badges for casting reopen votes outside a queue.
- Reopen vote stats are not prominently displayed anywhere, even in mod election stats.
- There is of course no direct rep to be gained.

That really only leaves one possibility for disreputable gain: someone thought they could *answer* all those questions and get a few upvotes, and perhaps a badge or three. (Checkmarks and bounties aren't likely.)

However, I'm not entirely convinced that someone finding ancient questions that they consider answerable and voting accordingly is particularly atrocious behavior. It doesn't fit the usual FGitW patterns, so it really isn't much of a get-rep-quick scheme. It's basically just another variant on "I really think this question should be reopened", and the possibility of some personal gain is counterbalanced by the usual checks and balances that FGitW partly bypasses — the OP isn't going to upvote/accept unless there's something genuinely useful there.

So in this case, there doesn't appear to be anything worth worrying about going on, except the usual distressingly poor judgement that an inevitable proportion of 3kers must by statistical necessity display.

Comment: Thanks, very useful. Especially the break-down of possible-but-inapplicable benefits. I agree that the reopen votes aren't atrocious behavior; I'm just puzzled by them. It is the lack of any obvious "nefarious" purpose, in spite of what _seems_ like behavior that would normally be driven only be nefarious purposes. It just seems so weird to me, too weird to be coincidence, but also too weird for me to understand what would motivate a non-coincidental outcome.

Comment: [Second option (if there's no reopen votes)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256830/792066)